# CartoDB simple process

Tags: polygon, sql, carto, line

I'm attempting to create a simple process with CartoDB, I have a layer with number of polygons, I want to to run a SQL with a multipoint line to report which polygons were intersected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple SQL statement,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ST_Intersects(the_geom, your_line_string)
```

Replace your_line_string with whatever way you want to supply the geometry. Two nice ways are either as WKT or as a GeoJSON text string.

First WKT

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(
    the_geom, 
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-160 -23.5, 160 -23.5)',4326)
  )
```

Second GeoJSON

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(
    the_geom, 
    ST_SetSRID(
      ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "LineString","coordinates": [ [-160, -23.5], [160, -23.5] ] }'),4326)
  )
```

Comment: I'm trying to show the linestring in the resulting map, can you just add LineString to the SELECT portion to show that?